# Get route data from within IResultFilter.OnResultExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When a view has been rendered in memory and before it is sent as a response to the client, I would like to intercept the call, check which view is being rendered, what was the action and controller, and do some house-keeping.

Therefore, I am implementing a `ResultFilter` and overriding the `OnResultExecuted` method.

Within this method, how do I get the route data to figure out which view, action, controller were called?

**Update**
My profuse apologies. I just looked up ResultExecutedContext in reflector and it showed me only an Exception, Cancelled and ActionResult property. It didn't show me any RouteData. When I fired up the IDE, it did show me the route data. I feel like a dick for asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get it from the `filterContext`'s [`RouteData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.routedata%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    RouteData rd = filterContext.RouteData;
    // read from the current request RouteData the information
    // you were looking for. For example to get the current controller
    // and action:
    string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
}
```

As far as which view was rendered is concerned you could retrieve this information from the [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.resultexecutedcontext.result%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property:

```
var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
if (viewResult != null)
{
    // the controller action returned a view result (either a ViewResult or PartialViewResult)
    // so we could retrieve the view name here:
    string viewName = viewResult.ViewName;
}
```

If on the other hand the controller action returned a JsonResult you could also extract retrieve it:

```
var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks, Darin. I get the idea. I just needed a track to run on. I feel ashamed having asked this question and a recently previous one about intercepting stuff (action filters), to which also you replied. I am usually not this stupid. I don't know what, if it is the pressure I am under that I am not thinking things through more recently.

Comment: No problem. There is nothing to be ashamed of. That's what StackOverfow is about - helping peer developers and learning new things.

Comment: It may well help others, particularly given the depth of Darin's response, so it's no bad thing

Answer (score 1):

`ResultExecutedContext` has a `RouteData` property which should give you what you need